# Set line to 0 if no measurements between dates in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have some values for showing in my chart:

[image]

But between 10th and 16th of september there is no measurement. I want that that period goes to 0.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.connectNulls) to false in this case. There wouldn't be a 0 value - it would appear as a gap. This depends on there being data elements present. If you data is not present (either as {x-value, null} or as x-axis categories and y data array) then you would have to pre-process your data to add either `null` or 0 y-values for the times with no data.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Ok. Thank you. I wondered if there was an option for that. I guess it will be hard to add too many measurements as null. I will leave it as it is right now.

Comment: It isn't very hard - if each data point is one day, you can define your start and end dates, and then run a for loop on those dates, incrementing by one day each time.  If there is no data point in your data for the current date, add a data point with a y value of null.